# Redux data not accessible inside a switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, mern

I have data that comes from MongoDB and is stored in Redux. The data is about the visibility of the components on the page. The value can either be true or false and hence I have a switch to Toggle between them. Following is the code to initialize the Switch according to the data from the store inside the switch component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { purple } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import getVisibility  from '../actions/visibility';

const PurpleSwitch = withStyles({
    switchBase: {
      color: purple[300],
      '&$checked': {
        color: purple[500],
      },
      '&$checked + $track': {
        backgroundColor: purple[500],
      },
    },
    checked: {},
    track: {},
  })(Switch);


const Visibility = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getVis = async () =>{
      await dispatch(getVisibility());
    } 
    getVis();
  }, [dispatch]);

const visibility = useSelector((state) => state.visibility);
 console.log(visibility);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.checked;
    let name = event.target.name;
    console.log(name + value);
    // setVisibility({
      // ...vis,   // Spread Operator               
      // [name]: value,
    // });
  }    
  
  const visible = event => {
    handleChange(event);
    props.sendData(visibility);
  }
  return(
      <div>
          {visibility.profile?<p>Hi</p>:<p>Bye</p>}
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.profile} onChange={visible} name="profile" />}
            label="Profile"
          />
        </FormGroup>  
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.contact} onChange={visible} name="contact" />}
            label="Contact"
          />
        </FormGroup>  
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.education} onChange={visible} name="education" />}
            label="Education"
          />
        </FormGroup>  
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.skills} onChange={visible} name="skills" />}
            label="Skills"
          />
        </FormGroup>  
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.experiences} onChange={visible} name="experiences" />}
            label="Experiences"
          />
        </FormGroup>  
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.projects} onChange={visible} name="projects" />}
            label="Projects"
          />
        </FormGroup>  
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.achievements} onChange={visible} name="achievements" />}
            label="Achievements"
          />
        </FormGroup>

      {/* {visibility.profile?<Profile />:null}      
      {visibility.contact?<Contact />:null}      
      {visibility.eduction?<Education />:null}      
      {visibility.skills?<Skills />:null}      
      {visibility.experiences?<Experiences />:null}      
      {visibility.projects?<Projects />:null}      
      {visibility.achievements?<Achievements />:null}           */}
    </div>
);
}
export default Visibility
```

Printing the variable visibility gives out the correct data and trying to access it from within the return within the ternary operator `{visibility.profile?<p>Hi</p>:<p>Bye</p>}` works as expected but calling the same variable inside the checked of the FormControlLable gives the value of undefined.

```
 <FormControlLabel
      control={<PurpleSwitch checked={visibility.profile} onChange={visible} name="profile" />}
      label="Profile"
    />
```

and hence the switches are acting weird. I have come to the conclusion that the switches are being updated for render before the data is set inside the visibility variable. How can I solve this issue? Action, Reducers, and API are all working fine as the data is finally being rendered in the ternary operator as desired.[This is a screenshot of the buttons that have value empty that can be seen in the Developers Console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq3eB.jpg)

```
Reducer.js
     const reducer = (visibility = [] , action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case 'FETCH_VISIBILITY':
                return action.payload;
            default:   
                return visibility;
        }
    }



export default reducer;
```

Action.js

```
import * as api from '../api';

// Action Creators
const getVisibility = () => async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchVisibility();
        dispatch({ 
            type : 'FETCH_VISIBILITY',
            payload: data[0]
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
export default getVisibility;
```

Comment: Looks like `visibility.profile` is undefined on at least 1 render. We'd need to see your reducer code/logic to see why. Is the `getVisibility` action really asynchronous? Please also include this action creator code. Please include all relevant code in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: console.log(visibility) --> what gets logged for this ? . On seeing your code it should get logged twice once with the `[]` and one more time with the actual data . Does it log twice ?

Comment: Yes, it is getting logged twice. I am getting undefined at first and then true twice while printing visiblity.profile.

Comment: Well, the initially undefined value is because your `visibility` initial state value is an empty array (`[]`) and there is no index/key `profile`. Any update from here will be whatever the value of `data[0]` is from your `getVisibility` action, it may or may not have a `profile` property. Can you update your question to include this `data` response?